# Membership/Forum Platform: Turn SMF into Portal, Import into Joomla, or Do Something Else?

Tags: content-management-system, joomla, forum

I've 1) a PHP-based membership site and 2) some SMF forums. I want to integrate these things, so that they have a shared sign-on; I also want to run some PHP functions that will determine the items to display for specific users, based on their individual profiles (as measured by values in the database).

So:

Would it be better (easier and less expensive to build, more robust) to make SMF the master login and member system, add on an SMF portal (such as TinyPortal or SimplePortal), and then add custom PHP and custom DB tables that would enable the membership functions I have in mind...

or would I be better off using something like Joomla as a CMS, importing my SMF forums into some Joomla forum system like NinjaBoard, and then adding some custom PHP...

or bridging my existing PHP-membership script (with its neat PHP functions) to SMF (or MyBB), trying to hack together a dual-login system...

or using some other, integrated CMS/Forum, like Viscacha or TikiWiki?

I assume using SMF, and the existing forums, as the main system would probably be the most robust and elegant way of doing this... but I'd appreciate any feedback and suggestions. :)

Answer (score 1):

Best way will be going into fully integrated solution, rather then going for bridging multiple solutions.

My suggestion would be 
Use Joomla + JomSocial (as membership functionality) + Ninjaboard/Kunena (as forum)